# Formula to supply a number based on the state

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to develop a formula to assign a value to a state which shall be used for further calculations but I am having an issue because the formula relates to another formula which turns out with an error  message as "Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute (13,016 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters".
Note that other formula fields have referred to the the same field as seen below and usually using the expression: (Location_Lookup__r.rkl__State__c) 
 [image: Other formula field using same field]

The formula developed is as below:

CASE(Location_State__c ,'AL',3, 'AK',1,'AZ',2, 'AR',6, 'CA',3, 'CO',2, 'CT',4, 'DE',5, 'FL',2, 'GA',4, 'HI',4, 'ID',4, 'IL',3, 'IN',2, 'IA',2,'KS',4, 'KY',6, 'LA',4, 'ME',1, 'MD',3, 'MA',5, 'MI',4, 'MN',4, 'MS',4, 'MO',4, 'MT',2, 'NE',1, 'NV',8, 'NH',4, 'NJ',5, 'NM',6, 'NY',3, 'NC',6, 'ND',4, 'OH',2, 'OK',3, 'OR',3, 'PA',2, 'RI',2, 'SC',4, 'SD',7, 'TN',6, 'TX',4, 'UT',3, 'VT',2, 'VA',4, 'WA',5, 'WV',3, 'WI',5, 'WY',5,0)

I will please need help with getting another formula or any modifications that can solve this limitation issue or another way of having the same solution without hitting the execution limit or having to do a trigger.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate field which could hold this number based on state.

Update that field through workflow field update or from process builder.

> CASE(Location_State__c ,'AL',3, 'AK',1,'AZ',2, 'AR',6, 'CA',3, 'CO',2, 'CT',4, 'DE',5, 'FL',2, 'GA',4, 'HI',4, 'ID',4, 'IL',3, 'IN',2, 'IA',2,'KS',4, 'KY',6, 'LA',4, 'ME',1, 'MD',3, 'MA',5, 'MI',4, 'MN',4, 'MS',4, 'MO',4, 'MT',2, 'NE',1, 'NV',8, 'NH',4, 'NJ',5, 'NM',6, 'NY',3, 'NC',6, 'ND',4, 'OH',2, 'OK',3, 'OR',3, 'PA',2, 'RI',2, 'SC',4, 'SD',7, 'TN',6, 'TX',4, 'UT',3, 'VT',2, 'VA',4, 'WA',5, 'WV',3, 'WI',5, 'WY',5,0)

And in the formula you could refer this field.

Comment: Thanks for this option. I would have loved to have all existing records updated but I shall go for this option for now and look for other means of getting the flow update existing fields.

Comment: That's good, for existing records just do a data migration, that will be easy. Prepare excel, do the vlookup to get the values, save as csv, and finally upload by dataloader